# GridDB on WIndows OS, C# client

Tags: c#, windows, griddb

1. Is there a community edition of GridDB server available to install on Windows server
2. Is there a c# (.net) client available to ingest data in to GridDB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not that I know of, but you can opt to install via docker:
   https://griddb.net/en/docs/documents/2-2-2_installation_docker.php
2. Currently available ones are Java, Python, Node.js, Golang 
   https://griddb.net/en/docs/documents/2-4-1_java_application.php